# react header component do not load after redirect to other component

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and I am facing an issue. My header component is not loading when I use `<Redirect to=''>`

app.js code

```
<Router>
    <Header />
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route exact path="/contact" component={Contact} />
        <Route exact path="/results/:search" component={Results} />
        <Route exact path="/details/:id" component={Details} />    
    </Switch>
    <Footer />
</Router>
```

On the homepage when I redirect to the results component than `<header />` do not load or show anything.

```
<Route exact path="/results/:search" component={Results} />
```

Not sure why the header component does not get loaded(show html) even I have simple HTML in it.
Please guide or let me know if you guys need more code to debug the issue.Thanks

Comment: Does your `<Footer/>` works as expected?

Comment: @AnkushVerma Yes footer works perfectly well without any issue

Comment: Try looking through the developer console at the `dom` .See if `header`is there.

Comment: @AnkushVerma Nope no luck

Comment: have you tried restarting the application?

Comment: @AnkushVerma in header component constructor I have used console.log("i am header ")  and there is no console msg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225251/discussion-between-peter-and-ankush-verma).